# How to count items in group with Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, count, blogs

I am using active record to return a grouped list of dates with the following code:

```
function get_archive_links(){

        $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
        $this->db->group_by('MONTH(date), YEAR(date)');
        $query = $this->db->get('blog'); 

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'date' => $row->date
        );
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Which when looped and echoed on my page returns:

- Febuary 2012
- January 2012
- December 2012

How can I count each item in the group and display it in my list? Example:

- Febuary 2012 (2)
- January 2012 (6)
- December 2012 (7)

I will be counting how many blog posts there where for each month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either remove the `GROUP BY` then count in PHP, or add a `->select('COUNT(id) AS num_posts')` to your AR query. I'd probably add the `->select()`, as it's less work :)

Comment: Not sure I quite understand, :-( Could you expand slightly if possible, thanks for help.

Comment: Add `$this->db->select('COUNT(id) AS num_posts');` in the first line of the function, then in your `foreach` loop add in `'num_posts' => $row->num_posts`

Comment: I just get a lot of Undefined property: stdClass::$id.

Comment: Replace `id` with the name of your primary key column (the unique ID associated with each blog post)

Comment: id is the name of my primary key column :-|

Comment: Oh, my bad, of course. If you don't specify a `select()` when you `get()`, it returns all columns - you need to add the columns you need into the `select()` - `$this->db->select('id', 'date', 'COUNT(id) AS num_posts');`

Comment: function get_archive_links(){
         
   $this->db->select('id', 'date', 'COUNT(id) AS num_posts');
   $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
   $this->db->group_by('MONTH(date), YEAR(date)');
   $query = $this->db->get('blog'); 

  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   $data[] = array(
    'id' => $row->id,
    'date' => $row->date,
    'num_posts' => $row->num_posts
   );
  }

  return $data;
 }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8173/discussion-between-joe-and-hairynuggets)

Answer (score 1):

You can it with sql count function. if you are using group by, count function returning count rows for row group.

like this,

```
function get_archive_links(){
    $this->db->select("count(*) as count, blog.*);
    $this->db->order_by('date','desc');
    $this->db->group_by('MONTH(date), YEAR(date)');
    $query = $this->db->get('blog'); 

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
            'id' => $row->id,
            'date' => $row->date,
            'count' => $row->count
        );
    }

return $data;
```

}

Comment: levye How would I write this to use model and controller than the view?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect but not shows zero counts if not exist post for category

here is my function,

```
function get_category_list()
{
    $this->db->select("count(*) as num_posts,cb_category.*");
    $this->db->where_in('cb_post.city', $city_ids);
    $this->db->join('cb_posts', 'cb_post.category = cb_category.cat_id or cb_post.parent = cb_category.cat_id', 'left');

    $this->db->order_by('cat_name_en', 'ASC');

    $this->db->group_by('cb_category.cat_id');

    $query = $this->db->get('cb_category');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  categories.*,
  COUNT(posts.category_id) AS `count`
FROM
  (categories
LEFT JOIN
    posts 
ON posts.category_id = categories.category_id)
GROUP BY
  Category_name;
```

I've got the answer for the zero count issue.